# How to correct include more than one images from more than one directory using latex \graphicspath

Tags: pdftex

I have problem about finding files in latex from server filesystem.

Here is my whole latex code for rendering business card.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[zw32010,crossmark]{ticket}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=50mm]{geometry}

    \graphicspath{{app/static/images/}{app/static/users_documents/146/}}

    \newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont}

    \renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}
    \newcommand{\vcard}[5]{\ticket{
        \put(7, 31.75){\tt \LARGE #1}
        \put(7, 9){\tt #2}
        \put(66, 7.5){\tt #3}
        \put(68, 22){\tt #4}
        \put(28, 12){\tt #5}
    }}

    \newcounter{numcards}
    \begin{document}

    \setcounter{numcards}{0}

    \whiledo{\thenumcards<1}{
      \stepcounter{numcards}
      \vcard
      {\includegraphics[width=54.23mm, height=15.87mm]{nic_int_logo_logobitmapmid_1v0.jpg}}
      {\includegraphics[width=19.84mm]{personal_photo_1.jpg}}
      {\includegraphics[width=13.23mm]{qr.png}}
      {\includegraphics[width=9mm, height=29.93mm]{gray.png}}
      {\parbox{\textwidth}{\large \myfont{Matija \\Lukic}}}
    }

    \end{document}
```

In my log file I get error:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `personal_photo_1.jpg' not found.

I've been trying to fix error by changing paths where images are located:

```
\graphicspath{{app/static/images/}{app/static/users_documents/146/}}
```

to

```
\graphicspath{{app/static/images/}{app/static/users\_documents/146/}}
```

Also, I tried to remove last slash in paths, and add line before each filename. I still get the same error.

Comment: Where _exactly_ is app/static in relation to the file being compiled? Also did you try `./app/static/...`  if app is a subfolder if the folder in which the file is being compiled.

Comment: File being compiled is in the same directory as app folder. I tried to add ./ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work if the images are in the same folder as the tex file? Then we can rule out the the issue is with the file names.

Comment: Also are you 100% sure this is the only error from the log file?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem.

If you use

```
\graphicspath{{app/static/images/}{app/static/users_documents/146/}}
```

you must add slash before filename like this:

```
{\includegraphics[width=54.23mm, height=15.87mm]{/nic_int_logo_logobitmapmid_1v0.jpg}}
  {\includegraphics[width=19.84mm]{/personal_photo_1.jpg}}
  {\includegraphics[width=13.23mm]{/qr.png}}
  {\includegraphics[width=9mm, height=29.93mm]{/gray.png}}
  {\parbox{\textwidth}{\large \myfont{Matija \\Lukic}}}
```

Now it works.